# Summing measurements

Tags: sql, esper

I have this code:

```sql
@Name("Creating_hourly_measurement_Position_Stopper for line 2") 
insert into CreateMeasurement 
select 
    m.measurement.source as source, 
    current_timestamp().toDate() as time, 
    "Line2_Count_Position_Stopper_Measurement" as type, 
    { 
        "Line2_DoughDeposit2.Hourly_Count_Position_Stopper.value",
        count(cast(getNumber(m, "Status.Sidestopper_positioning.value"), double)), 
        "Line2_DoughDeposit2.Hourly_Count_Position_Stopper.unit", 
        getString(m, "Status.Sidestopper_positioning.unit") 
    } as fragments 
from MeasurementCreated.win:time(1 hours) m 
where getNumber(m, "Status.Sidestopper_positioning.value") is not null 
  and cast(getNumber(m, "Status.Sidestopper_positioning.value"), int) = 1 
  and m.measurement.source.value = "903791" 
output last every 1 hours;
```

but it seems to loop. I believe it's because new measurement will modify this group, meaning it is constantly extending. This mean that recalculation will be performed each time when new data will be available.

Is there a way to count the measurement or get the total of the measurements per hour or per day?

Answer (score 0):

The stream it consumes is "MeasurementCreated" (see from) and that isn't produced by any EPL so one can safely say that this EPL by itself cannot possibly loop.

If you want to improve the EPL there is some information at this link: http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.2.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_basicfilter
By moving the where-clause text into a filter you can discard events early.

Comment: Doesn't the insert into CreateMeasurement then cause an event in MeasurementCreated?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the insert into CreateMeasurement then cause an event in MeasurementCreated?